# Rails images in seed file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, seed

I have the following file seed. I am trying to save the information in the DB, but this produces the following error. I do not know if I am calling the image load wrong or I am specifying something that does not exist, but I know that the file I try to upload with this is at the given path in the file.

```
historia1 = History.new({
title: "Capitán, el perro que vive junto a la tumba de su dueño",
description: "Desde que Miguel murió, su perro Capitán se siente muy solo. 
    Una de las formas que tiene de expresarlo y estar más cerca del que fue su amo 
    y cuidador es acercándose cada día a la tumba, en la ciudad argentina de Córdoba, 
    y tumbándose encima. Según explicó la esposa de Miguel, el perro fue un regalo para 
    su hijo. Días después de la muerte de Miguel, Capitán desapareció de casa; estuvo 
    durante un tiempo durmiendo en la calle, hasta que le perdieron el rastro. 
    Un día, madre e hijo fueron a visitar la tumba de Miguel y se encontraron allí a Capitán. 
    El perro se nos acercó ladrando, como si llorara, confiesan. 
    Aunque lo llamaron el can permaneció inmóvil, en la tumba. 
    Una semana más tarde volvieron al cementerio y se toparon de nuevo con Capitán. 
    Esta vez regresó con ellos a casa, pero sigue visitando la tumba de Miguel a diario.",
history_status: 'publicada',
user_id: 1,
images_attributes: {  
          picture:File.open('public/images/capitan.jpg'),
          name:"Capitán, el perro que vive junto a la tumba de su dueño"             
     }
})
historia1.save
```

The error:

```
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<File:public/images/capitan.jpg>
/home/adrian/Documentos/Ucab/Desarrollo/Proyecto/Entrega II/cloancionPrueba/pabigo/db/seeds/history_seed.rb:1:in `<main>'
/home/adrian/Documentos/Ucab/Desarrollo/Proyecto/Entrega II/cloancionPrueba/pabigo/lib/tasks/custom_seed.rake:8:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'
/home/adrian/Documentos/Ucab/Desarrollo/Proyecto/Entrega II/cloancionPrueba/pabigo/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/adrian/Documentos/Ucab/Desarrollo/Proyecto/Entrega II/cloancionPrueba/pabigo/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed:history_seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Models

history.rb

```
class History < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user, optional: true

   has_many :images, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy do
       def length
         reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).length
       end
   end

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true

   validates :title, presence: { message: 'El título no puede estar vacío' }
   validates :description, presence: { message: 'La descripción no puede estar vacía' }
   validates :title, length: { in: 5..75,
   too_long: " 50 caracteres es lo maximo permitido",
   too_short: " 5 caracteres es lo minimo permitido" }
   validates :description, length: { in: 5..2000,
      too_long: " 1500 caracteres es lo máximo permitido",
      too_short: " 5 caracteres es lo minimo permitido" }

   def self.search(search)
     if search
       where("title LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
     elsif search2
       where("created_at LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
     else
       find(:all)
     end
   end


end
```

image.rb

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
 attr_accessor :validate_picture

 belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
 mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader

 validates :picture, presence: true, if: :validate_picture?

 def validate_picture?
   validate_picture == 'true' || validate_picture == true
 end
end
```

Comment: Are you using paperclip to handle image uploads, something else?

Comment: No I'm using Carrierwave.

Comment: My guess is the parameter you are passing the image value into is wrong, for example, in paperclip the parameter generated for an `:image` field as an attachement is actually `:image_file_file_name `.  Not sure about carrierwave but I would look in the DB and just make sure it is not actually something like `picture_file_file_name` or something.

Answer (score 1):

You're super close.  And the error is a little unhelpful, because it makes you think there is something wrong with the image file, but it's not.

when you call objects_attributes: (plural) and not object_attributes: (singular) - then you need to wrap your object has in an array, because, potentially, there will/can be more than 1 hash.  Your seed should look more like:

```
history = History.new(
  title: "Capitán, el perro que vive junto a la tumba de su dueño",
  description: "Desde que Miguel murió, su perro Capitán se siente muy solo. 
    Una de las formas que tiene de expresarlo y estar más cerca del que fue su amo 
    y cuidador es acercándose cada día a la tumba, en la ciudad argentina de Córdoba, 
    y tumbándose encima. Según explicó la esposa de Miguel, el perro fue un regalo para 
    su hijo. Días después de la muerte de Miguel, Capitán desapareció de casa; estuvo 
    durante un tiempo durmiendo en la calle, hasta que le perdieron el rastro. 
    Un día, madre e hijo fueron a visitar la tumba de Miguel y se encontraron allí a Capitán. 
    El perro se nos acercó ladrando, como si llorara, confiesan. 
    Aunque lo llamaron el can permaneció inmóvil, en la tumba. 
    Una semana más tarde volvieron al cementerio y se toparon de nuevo con Capitán. 
    Esta vez regresó con ellos a casa, pero sigue visitando la tumba de Miguel a diario.",
    history_status: 'publicada',
    user_id: 1,
    images_attributes: [{
      picture: File.open('public/images/capitan.jpg'),
      name: "Capitán, el perro que vive junto a la tumba de su dueño"
    }]
)

history.save
```

Comment: thank you very much, following your advice, I wrapped it in an array, I verified and I also accommodated the error of the call that was in the singular and worked perfectly.